# Heroku Error - When running "rake heroku:gems --trace" command

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I tried to deploy my sample ruby application to heroku and I followed the steps mentioned in the link below: 
 
http://thejqr.com/2009/04/24/deploy-your-rails-application-in-2-minutes-with-heroku.html 
 
The attached screenshot shows the error page when I run the following command

```
   rake heroku:gems --trace
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.[image]

Comment: This is the contents of my heroku.rake file:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jqr/101101/raw

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the rake task is failing is because the method `Rails.configuration.gems` was available prior to Rails 3.

`Rails.configuration.gems` is trying to obtain the list of gems. A similar method is available in Bundler, but it'll only give you the list of dependencies, hence might not be useful.

```
    require 'bundler'
    mygems = Bundler.load.specs.map { |spec| spec.name }
```

However, **you need not do all this to deploy to heroku**. Simply create an app in Heroku using the command `heroku create`. This will automatically take care of setting the git configuration as well (run `git remote -v` to check).

If you've already created the app, you can use this command instead to set up git for it - `heroku git:remote -a app_name`

Then simply run `git push heroku master`